# Eclipse CDT project configuration

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to build a CDT project in Eclipse version3.8. I have given the paths of all the libraries in C/C++ General-->Paths and Symbols. But the compiler is not able to get the path of header files and I get the following error:

> E:...\NewWorkspace\...\strong\cpp\ck2/services/gpdm/TestRestBindingStub.hxx(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ck2\schemas\gpdm_2010_09\gbom\TestResponse.hxx': No such file or directory

I have also given all the paths in settings upto the root folder of .hxx file but still its not taking the header file and throwing error.

Please help.
Thanks in advance
NC

**EDIT-[Its not a duplicate]:**

Okay let me refine my question. 
I have included all the External include in my Eclipse CDT project. But its not able to recognize the one's which are present inside the project itself.

Example, I have a project at location:

> (Workspace-loc)/source/output/server/rootA/sub-rootA/file.hxx

I have include the path in *includes* till here:

> (Workspace-loc)/source/output/server/

And I include the file in my project like this:

```
#include <rootA/sub-rootA/file.hxx>
```

But I get an error saying:

> '......\file.hxx': No such file or directory

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ  Unfortunately that answer is somewhat out of date for Eclipse. I use the `pkg-config` plugin where possible:  https://code.google.com/p/pkg-config-support-for-eclipse-cdt/

Comment: @Galik: I agree but I am working on a legacy application. And that legacy application has provided a customized eclipse 3.8 c/c++ edition to make the customizations.